# What is the "status 53" error during wifi authentication?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I keep getting the following error when connecting to a Cisco/Meraki access point with 802.11r enabled. It happens after a certain time period and then the client blacklists the AP and is disconnected. When it connects again using a full eapol handshake, the connection recovers.

```
kernel: wlp2s0: f2:cb:ac:xx:xx:xx denied authentication (status 53)
```

This is using wpa_supplicant v2.4, and kernel 4.15.

Now, I'm fairly sure this is something to do with PMKID timing out and becoming invalid controller-side but I would like to have a source of truth for that assertion. I've dug into the linux kernel code and followed the error to get to this [list of codes](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b047602d579b4fb028128a525f056bbdc890e7f0/include/linux/ieee80211.h#L3021) but there isn't a 53 there.

So, my questions are:

1. Is that an incomplete list or is this a non-standard code?
2. What is the best source of truth for these codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [hostapd & wpa_supplicant](https://w1.fi/) source code says:

```
src/common/ieee802_11_defs.h:157:#define WLAN_STATUS_INVALID_PMKID 53
```

You can see the full list in [ieee802_11_defs.h](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/src/common/ieee802_11_defs.h).

(wpa_supplicant shares the source tree with hostapd, which is the most common AP implementation for Linux-based devices.)

> What is the best source of truth for these codes?

I would suggest the actual IEEE 802.11 standards document. (Plus all the amendments, but they usually get folded into the next release of the main 802.11 standard.)

It's not available for free, as far as I know. Fortunately, hostapd does a good job of keeping up with the news. Currently hostap's source code references:

```
/* Status codes (IEEE Std 802.11-2016, 9.4.1.9, Table 9-46) */
/* Reason codes (IEEE Std 802.11-2016, 9.4.1.7, Table 9-45) */
```

Comment: All IEEE 802 standards are available for free, starting 6 months after ratification (i.e. becoming an official standard). You just have to sign up for a free account and deal with the jankiness of the IEEE's site. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68